# Lawn Care Question: Battery vs. Gas Powered

Tags: lawn

As a new homeowner, I'm investigating the value of buying battery-powered or gas-powered lawn equipment. Since this is a sizable purchase, I wondered if any experienced homeowners could point me in the right direction.
Thank You,

Comment: I would say that this answer, while on the surface does appear to be good advice, falls short when it's taken to its logical conclusion, i.e; should the owner decide to perhaps only mow part of the yard that he actually needs & convert the rest or leave it to nature will potentially invite hosts of problems that at a glance may not be obvious to anyone who has not lived next to wildlife in any meaningful capacity. Allowing grass to grow tall starts a chain of events that inevitably will lead to reduced quality of life for the humans who also inhabit the same property, whether or not they live

Comment: @ZvonimirKokorovic I don't know where you live but in the places I lived the only wildlife a garden section left to nature will attract are insects and birds or maybe a mole. Overall I would consider this an increase in my human quality of life (it looks nicers and feels more alive). I have no idea what kind of wildlife that leads to reduced quality of life for humans you are referring to.

Comment: How big is the lawn?

Answer (score 7):

Depending on you, and lot size, decent (*i.e.* not poorly made stuff that doesn't actually work) manual equipment should also be considered, as it offers the same advantages of no gas cans, no clogged carburetors in spring if you didn't do adequate prep in fall, no oil changes, no fighting with it when it decides not to start, etc.

Or, if you can manage a bit of care to avoid cutting cords, plug-in electric equipment can also be far more cost effective than decent-quality battery equipment, since decent-quality batteries are rather expensive at present. But they do work a lot better than prior-era batteries.

If you have a particularly large area gas equipment tends to win at present, though one thing to think about with a particularly large area is "What purpose does all this lawn area *actually serve* in my life?" Possibly followed by converting some or all of it to some purpose that serves your life better and doesn't need so much mowing and other "lawn maintenance." Depending on locale and personal taste, that could be [xeriscaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeriscaping), flower beds, vegetable garden, orchard (still needs some mowing, usually,) zen garden, etc. Or possibly getting a mower suitable for your miniature golf course, lawn bowls, or passion for croquet or soccer.

If you are considering a battery mower anyway, you may want to consider a robotic mower if *having the lawn cut* rather than *you personally cutting the lawn* is your actual goal. They are also expensive, but if you have not bought a mower at all, the relative cost can be close, since you won't have the additional expense of a manual mower you may not use much after getting a robotic one. If properly set-up, they can work somewhat slowly but persistently without you being involved, rather than requiring a machine that you can get the whole lawn done with in a few hours when you have time.

Comment: I don't know if anyone's currently making one, but back when I was mowing a lawn, I had an electric mower with a handle that would flip from one end to the other.  It's a lot easier to keep from running over the cord if you don't need to turn the mower around after each pass.

Comment: "you may want to consider a robotic mower if having the lawn cut rather than you personally cutting the lawn is your actual goal" - is there anyone who genuinely enjoys the latter, not because he cannot affort a garden roomba?

Answer (score 3):

The optimum solution depends on a few things:

- size of lawn to be cut
- your budget as batteries with greater capacity cost more
- are you interested in purchasing additional tools that run on the same battery

I just purchased a battery mower and trimmer and like a few things:

- no need to have gas in the garage
- less need for extension cords
- can cut and trim a small lot with charge to spare
- less maintenance: no spark plugs, air filters, no oil to change

Things I don't like:

- what I bought does not seem powerful enough to provide a clean cut when the grass is high
- not powerful enough to blow clippings off the walk
- yet to be determined if it can mulch leaves in the fall

Answer (score 2):

I recently bought a house with over 1/2 acre of lawn to be mowed and a lot of perimeter to be trimmed.  I elected to go with a battery powered riding mower, which cost around $4000, and a ~60v string trimmer (around $200).  I'm very happy with both purchases.  The advantages of electric are 1) no need for tuneups, gasoline, oil changes, etc. 2) always easy to start.  3) no emissions.  I bought different brands but it is possible to buy additional equipment sans batteries to save money if they are compatible (i.e. blower, edger, hedge trimmer).  Also in the previous house I used a 60V push mower that could do the entire front or back yard on one charge.  It took about 7 charges to do the front yard on the new house.

Comment: 0.5 acres is more than 2000 square metres, or 2 decare. In a temperate climate that's enough to keep half a dozen sheep fed, or produce 7000 kg of potatoes.

Comment: @AkselA, and the point is? Envy?

Comment: @RohitGupta  No, I'm just trying to put it into perspective. I see a lot of deliberation about how to maintain a big lawn cheaply, when you could choose to see it as a major resource.

Answer (score 1):

This really comes down to the size of your property and price.

I changed from a supposed quality (STIHL) gas powered weed wacker to a generic 48 volt electric one with 2 batteries and never looked back.   I find it has plenty of power to trim even large weeds - not as powerful as the STIHL, but more then adequate with both line trimmer and a sold 3-blade disk.  The only disadvantage is that the limited run-time - that is somewhat mitigated by 2 batteries.

When investigating battery powered ride-on lawnmowers I was disappointed to see the technology (ie lithium based batteries) were still super expensive relative to their performance, so that might be a tough call.   I expect that walk-behind mowers will perform fine (based on my experience with weed wackers)

The really nice thing about electric is - they just work.   No changing oil filters, spark plugs, breaking your arm while trying to start them etc.   The batteries do have a finite life - so you probably need to weigh that up against the cost of servicing (to me batteries are a no-brainer here)

Also, depending on your budget, free time, if you have a smaller lawn - have you considered an automatic lawnmower [ like a Roomba for outside ]?  I've never used one - they cost as much as a gas ride-on, but are fairly fully automated once set up - and electric.

If you only have a small back yard and don't need to do a lot of maintenance, go battery powered - the more volts the better.    If you have money to burn, look for brushless motors - these provide higher performance and longevity).